# How to use loop and with_nested together in ansible

Tags: ansible, nested-loops

I have the vars defined like this-

```
  vars:
    values:
      - key1: value1 
        key2:
          - value1.1
          - value1.2

      - key1: value2 
        key2: 
          - value2.1
          - value2.2
```

Want to iterate on key1 with corresponding values in key2

I am running ansible 2.7.10 with python 2.7.10. Here is what I have written in my task based on some suggestions I found online-

(used with_subelements)

```
- name: test loops
  debug:
    msg: "This is key1: {{ item.0.key1 }}, and here is corresponding key2 element {{ item.1 }}"
  with_subelements:
    - values
    - key2
```

Expected output:

```
This is key1: value1, and here is corresponding key2 element value1.1
This is key1: value1, and here is corresponding key2 element value1.2
This is key1: value2, and here is corresponding key2 element value2.1
This is key1: value2, and here is corresponding key2 element value2.2
```

Error I get when I execute the playbook:

fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "subelements lookup expects a dictionary, got 'values'"}

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct syntax is

```
with_subelements:
  - "{{ values }}"
  - key2
```

, or [Migrated from with_X to loop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-subelements)

```
loop: "{{ values|subelements('key2') }}"
```

The play below

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    values:
      - key1: value1
        key2:
          - value1.1
          - value1.2
      - key1: value2 
        key2: 
          - value2.1
          - value2.2
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.0.key1 }} - {{ item.1 }}"
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ values }}"
        - key2
```

gives (abridged):

```
"msg": "value1 - value1.1"
"msg": "value1 - value1.2"
"msg": "value2 - value2.1"
"msg": "value2 - value2.2"
```